# Multiple server FTP download class

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, ftp

I've written this a short time ago. Do you see anywhere I can improve my logic? This is my first python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
from ftplib import FTP  # ftplib comes with the py install


class Ftp:

    def __init__(self, hostname, username, password, port=21):

        print '\nConnecting to %s on port %d' % (hostname, port)

        ftp = FTP()

        try:
            ftp.connect(hostname, port)
        except:
            raise Exception('\n\nConnection failed: %s:%d' % (hostname, port))

        try:
            ftp.login(user=username, passwd=password)
            self.start = ftp.pwd()

            print 'Login Successful: %s\n' % username
        except:  # ftplib.error_perm
            raise Exception('\n\nAuth: \n%s@%d\n\n' % (hostname, username))

        self.ftp = ftp
        self.hostname = hostname

    def end(self):
        try:
            self.ftp.quit()
        except:
            pass
        print '\n\nConnection to %s has been closed\n' % self.hostname

    def ls(self):
        return self.ftp.nlst()

    def get(self, file):
        return self.ftp.retrbinary(
            'RETR ' + file, open('%s/%s' % (self.hostname, file), 'wb').write)

    def cwd(self, file):
        return self.ftp.cwd(file)

    def pwd(self):
        return self.ftp.pwd()

    def download(self):
        print 'Downloading Files:'
        self._dl()
        print '\nAll Files Downloaded'
        self.end()

    def _dl(self, changedir='/'):

        if changedir is not '/':
            self.cwd(changedir)
        current = self.pwd()
        folders = []
        files = self.ls()

        for file in files:
            try:
                self.cwd(file)
                if current is not '/':
                    path = '%s%s/%s' % (host, current, file)
                else:
                    path = '%s%s%s' % (host, current, file)
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    os.makedirs(path)
                    if path != '%s/.' % host:
                        folders.append(path)

                self.cwd(current)
            except:
                if current is not '/':
                    self.get('%s/%s' % (current, file))
                else:
                    self.get('%s' % file)
                print '    %s' % file
        try:
            for fold in folders:
                print '  /%s' % fold
                self._dl(fold.replace(host, ''))
        except:
            pass
```

Usage:

```
hosts = ['domain01.com', 'domain02.com']
user = 'username'
password = 'secr3t'

for host in hosts:
    Ftp(host, user, password).download()
```

I tried to make it as [PEP8 compliant](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as it can be. It is a short file and straightforward. I need better commenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall - looks good and readable. Just a few comments.

- I didn't quite get it but looks like you are relying on exception to be thrown to get a signal and download file - this is bad and expensive.
  Is there a way to check if this is file and download instead of trying to treat it as directory - `cwd` - and catch exception.
  Is this what you are trying to do?

In general it is bad to organize program workflow around exceptions - they are for exceptional situations - not for routine work.

- Use `os.path.join` to concatenate paths - [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
- Use some constant like `ROOT_PATH` instead of hard-coding `'/'`
- Use `logging` module for debug/error logging - this is industry standard
- Don't swallow exceptions - log them, use extended `except`:

  `except Exception as e:`
- Minor - use `"{0}{1}/{2}".format(host, current, file)` instead of `%` notation as this is sometimes wonky and `format` is just better and industry standard.
- Small comment - you are hard-coding logic on where to download files on local disk inside `Ftp` class which is working but not the best - just add optional parameter to be able to override root directory where to download data to.

Answer (score 1):

You did a good job following the PEP, stylewise you're matching it for the most part. Though as Maxim pointed out you should use modern formatting. I have some small notes about things.

I'm confused about this inline comment here:

```
    except:  # ftplib.error_perm
```

Is that the error you're excepting? Then you should explicitly use it:

```
    except ftplib.error_perm:
```

You could also `raise` this specifically rather than a plain `Exception`:

```
        raise ftplib.error_perm('\n\nAuth: \n%s@%d\n\n' % (hostname, username))
```

This will raise it as the correct error and still print the string you're passing as the explanatory message.

If the comment is supposed to mean something else... then what? It's not clear from context, so it's not doing its job.

The bare `except` in `end` is *definitely* a bad idea. It will ignore any error that possibly arises when trying to quit the FTP, and then just tell the user that it closed fine. This is a bad idea generally but especially if you're not closing connections correctly. For instance, if you had made a typo and just written `self.fto.quit()` then your `except` would be ignoring it, and you won't be indicating that it happened at all.

Don't use `is` or `is not` for string comparison. It will often work due to something known as string interning, but there are cases where it can fail. The keyword `is` allows you to check *identity*. This means you're trying to identify if two things are the same, not just that they're equal. This is best used with `is None`, or when trying to tell if two names refer to the same object. Strings aren't a good use case because though it will often produce correct results it is unreliable and context dependent. Instead just use `==` and `!=`.

Avoid using `file` as a name. It's also the name of the builtin file constructor, so you're shadowing it by using it in your `for` loop.

Also you could shorten this with a ternary:

```
if current is not '/':
    path = '%s%s/%s' % (host, current, file)
else:
    path = '%s%s%s' % (host, current, file)
```

A ternary expression is basically an expression that will return one of two values, based on a tested expression. In your case you can test `if current == '/'`. It seems backwards to use the negative case here, so I flipped it.

```
path = ('{}{}{}' if current == '/' else '{}{}/{}').format(host, current, file)
```

This will use either the string `'{}{}{}'` or `'{}{}/{}'` depending on whether or not `current == '/'`. It's debatable whether or not this is clearer or more readable, but I think it's better for indicating what difference that result actually makes.